# Switch fails to render component in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hey Guys im kinda stuck on a simple matter,
my routing doesn't work, no idea why

The Code:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
<div className="App">
  <Header></Header>
    <Switch>
      <Route component={Home}  exact path='/'></Route>
      <Route component={ToyApp} exact path='/app'></Route>
    </Switch>
</div>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

NavBar:

```
   <nav>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <NavLink to='/'>Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/app'>App</NavLink>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </nav>
```

Only the Home Component Renders even if i go to /app, when i change their order only the app component appears.

Edit:
When i change the url by hand in browser it works, so problem must be with the nav

Comment: This type of problem might be easier to help with if there was a codepen or something to view the behavior with.

Comment: What are you using to navigate to the other path? Is it directly in the browser?

Comment: Added the navbar

Comment: Remove the second `BrowserRouter`. The two routers won't interact with each other, you only need one. Within one Router you may have as many `Switch`'s `Route`'s and `Link`'s as you want. Just make sure all of those components are descendants of the `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: As others pointed out, you don't need router in navbar. You only need router in app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the BrowserRouter wrapping your NavLinks. BrowserRouter should be used once at the very root of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Why `Browser Router`? If you are using a dynamic server that can handle dynamic URLs then you need to use the BrowserRouter component else  if you are using a server that only serves static files you can use `HashRouter`.

A `Link` component takes a to property which tells React Router the destination to navigate to. `NavLink` is a subclass of Link which adds styling information to the rendered element(s) (You can use any of the either.)

You can use your component inside BrowserRouter .Posting Just a reference:

```
class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li><Link to={'/'} className="nav-link"> Home </Link></li>
                <li><Link to={'/contact'} className="nav-link">Contact</Link></li>
              </ul>
              </nav>
              <hr />
              <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                  <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        );
      }
    }
```

For More : https://www.techiediaries.com/react/react-router-5-4-tutorial-examples/